# "Following arguments are required" but I have already declared them (in Python machine learning project)

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, argparse

I am currently working on a project aimed to teach deaf people and their loved ones TSL(Turkish Sign Language). I am using machine learning to do so but I can't seem to train the programme with my alphabet dataset due to an error

```
usage: train.py [-h] -d
                C:\USERS\MELISA\DESKTOP\ISITME_ENGELLILER_PROJE\MACHINE_LEARNING\DATASET
                -m
                C:\USERS\MELISA\DESKTOP\ISITME_ENGELLILER_PROJE\MACHINE_LEARNING\MODEL
                -l
                C:\USERS\MELISA\DESKTOP\ISITME_ENGELLILER_PROJE\MACHINE_LEARNING\LABEL_BIN
                [-e 10]
                [-p C:\USERS\MELISA\DESKTOP\ISITME_ENGELLILER_PROJE\MACHINE_LEARNING\PLOT]
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\dataset, -m/--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\model, -l/--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\label-bin
```

I am trying to work the code from this website https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/15/video-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/. I would really appreciate the help, thanks.

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", r"--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", r"--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\model", required=True,
    help="path to output serialized model")
ap.add_argument("-l", r"--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\label-bin", required=True,
    help="path to output label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--10", type=int, default=10,
    help="# of epochs to train our network for")
ap.add_argument("-p", r"--C:\Users\MELISA\Desktop\isitme_engelliler_proje\machine_learning\plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
args= ap.parse_args()
```

I am trying to work the code from this website https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/15/video-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/. I have seen questions similar to mine but the answers seem to suggest using code in the form of mine. I would really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: The tutorial uses lines like `ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
 help="path to input dataset")`.  You tried to substitute a `rstring` for `--dataset`.  That's not the way to "declare" them.  Stick with the the '--dataset' string in the `add_argument`.  You are supposed to supply the file name(s) as commandline arguments (to a script, not a notebook).

Comment: How can I supply the file names as commandline arguments? I have tried to put the file name instead of dataset after -- but of course that did not work. Where else can I put it, do I need to add another line of code? Also what did you mean by rstring?

Comment: do you know what we mean by commandline arguments? Are you running this as a script or notebook?

Comment: running tutorials without some basic python knowledge will be frustrating.

Comment: I've tried it both as a script and in a notebook. I do know the language, but machine learning incorporates many other python libraries so the functions change up a bit. I just don't know where to put the database file location so it can be used as a source.

Comment: this isn't a machine learning issue.  `argparse` is a basic python module ussd to derive information from user input - from `sys.argv`

Comment: Well I had difficulties implementing it in my project, so could you please tell me what changes or new lines of code are necessary? I need to be able to put my database at hand as an input.

Comment: Your tutorial page has a link to a page that explains their use of `argparse` and `commandline arguments`.   https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/03/12/python-argparse-command-line-arguments/